# F#: Creating a new record from an existing one, with lists

Tags: list, f#, record

Supposing I have a type defined as follows:

```
type State = { intList : int list }
```

and a value as follows:

```
let a = { intList = [1; 2; 3; 4] }
```

Now supposing I want a new value `b` with `a`'s values with 5 added to the end.  I can't figure out how to do it using the `with` syntax.  Also I can't figure out how to get a new state having one fewer element, for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `with` syntax (copy-and-update expression) doesn't allow for creating a record based on a modified property of another record, only copying some properties (intact) and replacing others. You can use normal record constructors:

```
let a = { intList = [1; 2; 3; 4] }
let b = { intList = a.intList @ [1; 2; 3; 4; 5] }
let c = { intList = List.tail a.intList }
```

Answer (score 2):

As Daniel said, there is no specific syntax to read a property from the record you are copy-and-updating. But you still can access it using normal dot notation:

```
let a = { intList = [1; 2; 3; 4] }

let b = { a with intList = a.intList @ [5] }
```

Of course, in this case the `with` is pretty useless since you're updating all the fields, so you might as well just use the new record syntax (as shown by Daniel). But if the record also has fields that you want to preserve from `a` to `b`, this is how I would do it.